# Trouble getting memory allocated for char* in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

So I'm having trouble allocating memory for a char* being passed into the constructor of my shape class, I keep getting an error saying "malloc: *** error for object 0x1001000e0: pointer being freed was not allocated". I did a lot of googling and I find answers but they don't make sense, I don't understand what's wrong. shapeName is a protected char* member of shape. Square is a child of shape. If someone could explain what is wrong that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

My Constructor:

```
Shape::Shape(Point* origin,char* name) {
   this->origin = origin;
   this->shapeName = (char*) new char(strlen(name)+1);
   strcpy(shapeName, name);
}
```

My Destructor:

```
Shape::~Shape() {
   delete shapeName;
   delete origin;
}
```

Square's Constructor:

```
Square::Square(Point* origin, char* squareName, double side) 
: Shape(origin, squareName){
   side_a = side;
}
```

My call:

```
Square s(new Point(5,7),"Square - S", 12);
s.display();

cout << "The area of " << s.getName() << " is: " << s.area() << endl;
cout << "The perimeter of " << s.getName() << " is: " << s.perimeter();
```

Comment: I've heard of casting `malloc`, but I've never heard of casting `new`.

Comment: Why not use std::string? It will manage the memory automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
this->shapeName = (char*) new char(strlen(name)+1);
```

You're making a single char, and setting its value to strlen(name)+1. The strcpy() then overruns the end of the (single-byte) allocation, and the heap structure 'delete' tries to operate on is broken.

This is what you want instead (different brackets):

```
this->shapeName = new char[strlen(name)+1];
```

Also, there is a special 'array delete' you must use if you want to be correct:

```
delete[] shapeName;
```